# Exported files from GeoTracker (kml,kmz.gpx) are not visible after certain zoom in QGIS

Tags: kml, gpx, zoom, kmz, visibility

I have problem with track recorded with GeoTracker on my Android. Exported track, either in any of given formats: gpx, kml or kmz, is not visible after certain zoom level - scale **1:6.141** (I am using QGIS v2.18.5), and I must note that this is only happening with linestring, not points. Option to set scale visibilty for selected layers in QGIS is not enabled, so QGIS is not a problem. I also exported all the files into shapefile just to try if it would maybe work, but it is still not visible, because logically I guess it withdraws attributes from the original file. I ve been checking out visibilty in files itself, however it states 1. I didnt have problem with track I ve recorded after this one, where configuration and options were exactly the same. I need to be able to edit track somehow.

Comment: I've had this happen when a polygon shapefile had invalid geometries. The display was behaving erratically with features disappearing as I zoom in and appearing as I zoom out. Not sure if this might be the source of your problem but it is something you can easily check with topology checker.

Comment: Thnx for suggestion! I ve added all the rules and started topology checker. I have quite a few errors: dangling ends, one pseudo node. But this is expected since I couldnt reach a signal sometimes. The major note is that this happend with a track I ve recorded after this one and I could edit it without a problem. Or I assume...

Comment: You're welcome! Invalid geometries are when a feature self intersects or has duplicate nodes. I don't think dangles or pseudo nodes are an issue. What I related in my comment is what happened to me, the cause of your problem could be something else.

Answer (score 2):

I have soloved this with a little workaround:

1. I imported `track_points` part of the `gpx` file (because I could zoom in to points without any problem)
2. I have installed QGIS plugin `Points2One` and created lines from layer `track_points` with it